# the value of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\cos t dt$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be analytic function then what is the value of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})\cos t dt$?

Comment: $f$ is analytic in which domain?

Comment: all of unit disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=e^{it}$ the the integral becomes $$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)({z+z^{-1}\over 2}){dz\over iz}=0={1\over 2i}\int_{|z|=1} f(z)dz+{1\over 2i}\int_{|z|=1}{f(z)\over z^2}dz=\pi f'(0)$$.

Comment: No, firstly, $\cos t = \frac12(z + z^{-1})$, not $\frac12(z-z^{-1})$, but more importantly, it's not $dt = izdz$ but $dt = \frac{dz}{iz}$.

Comment: Note that the changes affect the outcome as well. Referring to @DanielFischer's comment above, I'd suggest assuming $f$ to be analytic in some annulus containing the unit circle, and answering in terms of $f$'s Laurent coefficients.

Comment: I think it is okay now?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic in the entire disk, yes, otherwise, the first integral need not vanish, and $f'(0)$ need not exist. Then the Laurent expansion @JonathanY. mentioned should be used.