# What is the value of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it}) \cos t \, dt$ if $f$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> If $f(z)$ is an analytic function, then find the value of the integration
> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it}) \cos t \, dt.$$

**My Work**:
Taking $e^{it} = z$ the integrand becomes of the form

$$i\frac{f(z)\operatorname{Re(z)}}{z}$$

on the simple closed contour $|z|=1$. But how can I proceed from here? Please help.

Comment: See, before you do any manipulation, just try some $f$. For example, $f$ identically equal to $0$, then the integral is $0$. So the answer is zero. Remember that $\cos t = \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}$, so that has to help as well.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540849, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2586219 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7Df(e%5E%7Bit%7D)%20%5Ccos%20t%20%5C%2C%20dt%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you write $\cos t$ as $\frac {e^{it}+e^{-it}} 2$ you will see that the integral is $\frac  1 {2i}\int_{\gamma} \frac  {f(z){(1+z^{2})}} {z^{2}}$. You can evaluate this  using Cauchy's Integral Formula or the Residue Theorem.